# Why cant we cast vector to set in java

Tags: java, vector, hashmap, set, hashset

While trying to cast vector to set in java. It threw an exception that

> cant cast to vector to set whereas we can cast vector to list.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast to supertypes or subtypes only. For example, you can cast from a `Number` to an `Integer` or from an `Integer` to a `Number`, but you cannot cast a `Vector` to a `Set`.

You can convert a `Vector` to a `Set`, like this:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(vector);
```

Note that you should use `ArrayList` rather than `Vector` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Casting works **vertically**, not **horizontally**. In other worcs reference can be cast to its supertypes or subtypes, like

```
   A
   |
+--+--+
|     |
B     B2
|
C

class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class B2 extends A{
    void foo(){}
}
```

and you have

```
B b = new C();
```

than

```
C c = (C)b;//fine since b really holds C instance
A a = (A)b;//also OK since A interface is guaranteed to have proper implementation 
           //inherited by B type (or even its subtype)
```

but

```
B2 b2=(B2)b;//will not compile because there is a chance that object stored in 
            //b will not provide implementation of interface of B2 type 
            //like `foo` method
```

So since `Set` is not super nor subtype of `Vector` you can't use casting.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Vector` does not extend `Set`. `Set`and `List` are 2 different interfaces that both extend `Collection`.

Analogy: Apple and Banana both inherit from Fruit. RedApple can be cast to Apple or Fruit, but cannot be cast to Banana.

You may do something alike instead:

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>(vector);
```